# java hashtable to c# dictionary

Tags: java, c#, dictionary, xamarin, hashtable

Java code:

```
//BleDevice is a class
public Hashtable<String, BleDevice> meusBLEs = new Hashtable<String, BleDevice>();

//BleRequest is another class
BleRequest currentRequest = null;

//deviceAddress is a string from BleRequest
BleDevice ble=meusBLEs.get(currentRequest.deviceAddress);
```

I'm using a hashtable and set the value to the BleDevice variable;

Now what I'm trying to do in c#, is the same thing but using Dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<String, BleDevice> meusBLEs = new Dictionary<String, BleDevice>();

BleRequest currentRequest = null;

BleDevice ble = meusBLEs.get...//HERE'S IS WHAT I DON`T KNOW HOW TO DO. THE METHOD GET DON`T EXIST
```

I can't use hashtable in c# cause I can't set the parameter  like java's hashtable.

Answer (score 4):

```
BleDevice ble = meusBLEs[currentRequest.deviceAddress];
```

Comment: FYI, unlike Java, this method of retrieving a value throws an exception if the requested key is missing from the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is a bit different in .NET than Java; in particular, while the Java's `get()` method may return `null` for missing values, such a convention is not applicable in .NET where the value type may not be a reference type.

There are actually two standard ways to retrieve a value:

```
BleDevice ble = meusBLEs[currentRequest.deviceAddress];
```

The statement above will throw an exception if the value for key `currentRequest.deviceAddress` is not present in the dictionary.  Alternatively, you can use the `TryGetValue` method:

```
BleDevice ble;
/* bool found = */ meusBLEs.TryGetValue(currentRequest.deviceAddress, out ble);
```

If `TryGetValue` returns `false`, the value of the `out` parameter will be `default(TValue)`.

Comment: You can use the following extension method to reproduce the Java behavior exactly: internal static TValue GetValueOrNull<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
 {
  TValue ret;
  dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out ret);
  return ret;
 }

Answer (score 1):

Just do this: `BleDevice ble = meusBLEs[the_key_you_have]`.